# Gunicorn on Nginx error handing request

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

When I run a Flask app with gunicorn with the following command:

```
gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 myapp:app
```

I am getting the following error after setting my browser to www.mayapp.com

```
[ERROR] Error handling request /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/me/.virtualenvs/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 130, in handle
    self.handle_request(listener, req, client, addr)
  File "/me/.virtualenvs/myapp/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/sync.py", line 171, in handle_request
    respiter = self.wsgi(environ, resp.start_response)
TypeError: app() takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

For the route in question I am using:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('myapp/index.html')
```

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in the python path I was using for an ansible deployment script. App worked OK when corrected

eg

```
wsgi_env_vars: {
    PYTHONPATH: '${PYTHONPATH}:{{ app_dir }}',
```